# How to schedule task using Quartz.net 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, quartz.net-2.0

I am trying to schedule a task using Quartz.net 2.0 in ASP.NET MVC 4 application, but i can not get the task to be executed.

Here is the code:

```
public class ScheduleTaskConfig
{
    public static void StartScheduler()
    {
        ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();

        IScheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();

        JobKey emailSenderTaskKey = new JobKey("emailSenderTask", "email");
        IJobDetail emailSenderTask = JobBuilder.Create<QueuedEmailsSendTask>()
            .WithIdentity(emailSenderTaskKey)
            .Build();

        TriggerKey emailSenderTriggerKey = new TriggerKey("emailSenderTrigger", "email");
        ITrigger emailSenderTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity(emailSenderTriggerKey)
            .WithSimpleSchedule(s => s.RepeatForever().WithIntervalInSeconds(5))
            .StartNow()
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(emailSenderTask, emailSenderTrigger);
        scheduler.Start();
    }
}
```

It is called in global.asax application start

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ScheduleTaskConfig.StartScheduler();
    ...
}
```

And here is the class that implements the IJob interface:

```
public class QueuedEmailsSendTask : IJob
{
    private IQueuedEmailsService _queuedEmailsService { get; set; }
    private IEmailSenderService _emailSenderService { get; set; }

    public QueuedEmailsSendTask(IQueuedEmailsService queuedEmailsService, IEmailSenderService emailSenderService)
    {
        this._queuedEmailsService = queuedEmailsService;
        this._emailSenderService = emailSenderService;
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext executeContext)
    {
        //do stuff ...
    }
}
```

I placed a breakpoint at the beginning of the Execute method, but the debugger does not stop there. What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
It has something to do with the class that implements the IJob interface not having a default constructor.
It works, if I modify the constructor like this:

```
public QueuedEmailsSendTask()
{
}
```

But I need to be able to inject my dependencies. I am using the Autofac IoC container.

Comment: Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET is not a very good idea (more info [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make Quartz.net work with an IoC container you need to have a factory class implementing IJobFactory:

```
public class AutofacJobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public AutofacJobFactory(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return (IJob)_container.Resolve(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
    }
}
```

The JobFactory instance then needs to be assigned to the scheduler in the initialization code:

```
ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
IScheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
scheduler.JobFactory = new AutofacJobFactory(container);
```

And don't forget to register the job in the IoC container.

Comment: When i debug, in the NewJob method I get the following exception: "No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself."

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried scheduling the job after starting the scheduler?

```
public class ScheduleTaskConfig
{
    public static void StartScheduler()
    {
        ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();

        IScheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
        scheduler.Start(); //start here   

        //construct job info

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(emailSenderTask, emailSenderTrigger); //schedule here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the `AutofacJobFactory` is responsible for instantiating the job. This means not using the `JobBuilder` object. Instead you should pass the details of the job to be created by the scheduler's `AutofacJobFactory` in the form of a `JobDetailImpl`  object. Your working code would look something like the following.

```
ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();

IScheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
scheduler.JobFactory = new AutofacJobFactory(container);
scheduler.Start(); //start here  

// construct job info
JobDetailImpl jobDetail = new JobDetailImpl("emailSenderTask", null, typeof(QueuedEmailsSendTask));

TriggerKey emailSenderTriggerKey = new TriggerKey("emailSenderTrigger", "email");
ITrigger emailSenderTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity(emailSenderTriggerKey)
    .WithSimpleSchedule(s => s.RepeatForever().WithIntervalInSeconds(5))
    .StartNow()
    .Build();

sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

For a complete example, please see the following question [How do I create a Quartz.NET’s job requiring injection with autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908342/how-do-i-create-a-quartz-nets-job-requiring-injection-with-autofac/16909555#16909555)